# Pycaffe Net forward_all() function not working

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe

After I trained some weights of a CNN, I decide to use the same net architecture to do the prediction.
I set my data `batch_size = 64`.

I can properly run the `pred_net.forward()` function, and I can get the predicted classes from `blobs['prob']`.

There are 20000 samples in my dataset. If I call `forward()` function for `i` times, I will get `64*i` samples forwarded to the net. So I can not cover the 20000 samples without forwarding some samples twice.

Therefore, I tried the `forward_all()` function. But I got an exception without any useful information. I don't know what's wrong.

I expected that `forward()` and `forward_all()` are similar(but not).

Here are the part of my code and the error message:

```
pred_net = caffe.Net(pred_net_proto_file, 'kg_trained.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)

pred_net.forward_all()
```

---

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-cefd35621a35> in <module>()
----> 1 pred_net.forward_all()

/home/microos/Space/caffe-master/python/caffe/pycaffe.pyc in _Net_forward_all(self, blobs, **kwargs)
    197         all_outs[out] = np.asarray(all_outs[out])
    198     # Discard padding.
--> 199     pad = len(six.next(six.itervalues(all_outs))) - len(six.next(six.itervalues(kwargs)))
    200     if pad:
    201         for out in all_outs:

StopIteration:
```

**Hopefully, I described things clearly.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to pass the data you want to forward to the forward_all() function:

```
pred_net = caffe.Net(pred_net_proto_file, 'kg_trained.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
pred_net.forward_all(data=data_samples)
```

suppose your CNN expects images of the shape (3,224,224) then your data_samples should have the shape (20000,3,224,224)

Comment: According to your answer, it seems to need to inject some data in the `forward_all`. But in my `prototxt, net define` my data source is `lmdb`, can I use the data inside the `prototxt`? Thanks